# How to move a button along x-axis while using ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to move a button(button1) when I click on it threw the x-axis.

Here is my code:

```
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    currentX=btn.getX();
    currentY=btn.getY();
    moveX=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(btn,"translationX",currentX,currentX+10);
    moveY=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(btn,"translationY",currentY,currentY);
    set=new AnimatorSet();
    set.playTogether(moveX,moveY);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v){
            set.start();
            currentX=v.getX();
            currentY=v.getY();
        }
    });
```

It moves at the first click, but after that it just starts from the beginning, instead of moving 10dp further on the x-axis. what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You need to either create a new animator or you need to update the values of the `moveX` and `moveY` animations. (Actually, you do not need the `moveY` animation since you are not changing the Y position.)

Also, Views have a more performant animation capability using `.animate()` to acquire a `ViewPropertyAnimator`. I would refactor your code this way:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btn.animate().xBy(10).start()
    }
});
```

If later you decide you also want to animate the Y position, you can simple add `.yBy(value)` before the `.start()`.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think the v.getx will change after the anime

try this :

```
int multi =1;
btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
currentX=btn.getX();
currentY=btn.getY();
moveX=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(btn,"translationX",currentX+10*(multi-1),currentX+10*multi);
moveY=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(btn,"translationY",currentY,currentY);
set=new AnimatorSet();
set.playTogether(moveX,moveY);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v){
        set.start();
        multi++;
        currentY=v.getY();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not holding the position of x-axis to which your button has moved,after click you set it again to intial value.

Change these lines

use a static variable.

```
static int x_axis=10+btn.getX();


currentX=x_axis;
currentY=btn.getY();
moveX=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(btn,"translationX",currentX,currentX);
moveY=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(btn,"translationY",currentY,currentY);
set=new AnimatorSet();
set.playTogether(moveX,moveY);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v){
        set.start();
        x_axis=x_axis+10;
        currentY=v.getY();
    }
});
```